# How can I run selected lines in Spyder 4?

Tags: python, ide, spyder, customization

In previous versions of Spyder, you can select lines in the editor, and only run those selected lines.

In Spyder 4, when you select lines and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> it executes `runcell(0, '/your/dir/file.py')` which runs the whole code.

How can I run just the lines which I have selected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The hotkey for running a the line at which the cursor is, or the currently selected lines in Spyder 4 is <kbd>F9</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will run the current *cell*. You can read more about cells in Spyder [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/editor.html). Basically, these are blocks of code that can be defined in the editor using a specific syntax within the code, and can be run independently by Spyder and other IDEs.

Incidentally, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for running the current line in R Studio, not Spyder, which may be where you got it confused.

Comment: In spyder 3.x Ctrl+Enter run the currently selected cell too.
Just figured out today that i can go to:
Tools -> Preferences -> Shortcuts 
and customize it, so i just used one single shortcut, which makes it fast to select with mouse on right hand and press the shortcut with left hand.

Answer (score 9):

In Spyder 4.0.1, the keyboard shortcut for 'run cell' is set to Ctrl+Return but for 'run selection' it is set to F9. You can use F9 to run a selection or if you prefer to use Ctrl+Return, you can go to Tools -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts. Search for 'run selection', double click and set Ctrl+Return as the 'New shortcut'

Comment: it work, just need to restart spyder, after setting changes

Answer (score 3):

In Spyder, you can split code into runnable cells

Use the the pattern `# In[]` or `#%%` to define the start of a new cell. You can also add child cells with additional `%`

[image: Spyder iPython Cells]

Answer (score 2):

In Spyder 4 the keyboard shortcut to run the highlighted lines of code is **F9**. and if you want to use any other shortcut then you can change it from **TOOLS>>PREFERENCES>>KEYBOARD SHORTCUTS** then double click on any shortcut you want to change and change with your shortcut. but be very careful if you used the same shortcut that is used for any other work then for that it will remove.