# Select code and run IDE/code editor for Python

Tags: python, ide

Is there an IDE/code editor for Python that allows a user to highlight and run a portion of syntax on the window like how SAS allows it in its UI? I'm aware of code blocks in Jupyter Notebook but I would like to know if there's something that's more flexible/free-form exists?

Comment: Hi I think, there something like this in Spyder you can divide your code in executable cells like in Jupyter or other notebooks and you can execute with Ctrl + Enter.

Comment: VSC : highlight your code, hit `shift+enter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there something like this in Spyder you can divide your code in executable cells like in Jupyter or other notebooks and you can execute with Ctrl + Enter.
This hotkeys and shortcuts have been discussed here if you need more informations.

[Stack answer on hotkeys in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266851/how-can-i-run-selected-lines-in-spyder-4)